# Heroku app: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwa'

Tags: python, django, heroku, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and I keep getting this error even though when I run locally it works perfectly fine. I have added django-pwa==1.0.10 to my requirments.txt file also so that heroku installs the package. Here are my installed apps in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pwa',
    # 'embed_video',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'courses.apps.CoursesConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'announcements.apps.AnnouncementsConfig',
    'students.apps.StudentsConfig',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'event_calendar.apps.EventCalendarConfig',
]
```

[Here is my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRNqN.png)

Not really sure what to do as I am not very experienced with heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Heroku will try to install every app from your requirements.txt, so before going any further make sure of the following:

- You have run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`to reflect the change
- Your path for the Procfile is correct

If it does not work after the troubleshooting, add your log from heroku to your first question, your procfile and requirements.txt.

[Learning about procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: sorry for the late response, Even though I added the apps to requirements manually this command seemed to work! Thank you for the help